# PHP: Want fsockopen to retrieve portion only of remote xml file

Tags: php

I need to retrieve a small amount of data from a very large remote XML file that I access via http.  I only need a portion of the file at the beginning, but the files I am accessing can often be so large that downloading them all will cause a timeout.  It seems like it should be possible with fsockopen to pull only as much as needed before closing the connection, but nothing I have tried has worked.

Below is a simplified version of what I have been trying.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do differently?

```
<?php

 $k = 0;

 function socketopen($funcsite, $funcheader){

 $fp = fsockopen ($funcsite, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);

 $buffer = NULL;

 if ($fp) {

    fwrite($fp, "GET " . $funcheader . " HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " . $funcsite. "\r\n\r\n");


 while (!feof($fp)) {
    $buffer = fgets($fp, 4096);
    echo $buffer;

    if($k == 200){
        break;
    }
    $k++;
  }

    fclose ($fp);
  } else {
    print "No Response:";
 }
 return ( html_entity_decode($buffer));
}

$site = "www.remotesite.com";
$header = "/bigdatafile.xml";
$data = socketopen($site, $header);
?>
```

This works fine, but always opens and downloads the entire remote file.  (I actually use a different conditional than the if($k = x), but that shouldn't matter).

Any help greatly appreciated.  -Jim

Answer (score 4):

**Any reason not to use `file_get_contents()` instead?**

```
$buffer = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.remotesite.com/bigdatafile.xml', 0, null, $offsetBytes, $maxlenBytes));
```

**You just need to specify `$offsetBytes` and `$maxlenBytes`.**

---

**Try this:**

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo $buffer = html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.remotesite.com/bigdatafile.xml', 0, null, 1024, 4096));
```

Comment: Removed my answer and upvoted yours because it's the best way of approaching the problem imo.

Comment: sure first i also thouth to use file_get_contents() but i didnt :(

Comment: This makes sense, but when I try it I still get the entire file downloaded before anything happens.  Big files still time out. Is there something else I need to do?

  Jim H.

Comment: @Jim: How many bytes are you retrieving? I think you must be doing something wrong, check the updated snippet on my answer and tell me if it works.

Comment: @Alix:  Thanks for the help.  I tested your script with a copy of one of the files on my own server and it works fine there.  I think the problem may be that the remote file is being generated dynamically. I don't know the exact size, but estimate up to 50MB. With 10MB on the remote site your script needs 40 seconds.  Its microseconds for the file on my own server.  Is there something else I can do in this situation?  -Jim H.

Comment: @Jim: Well I guess you could make use of `curl_multi` functions but that would be a lot harder, do you mind sharing the URL of the XML file you're parsing?

Answer (score 0):

with this code you could download the entire rss

```
  if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://remotesite.com/bigrss.rss))
    {
       throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load or parse  feed');
    }

  else
  {
    file_put_contents($xml,'mybigrss.rss'); 
  }
```

but if you want to get just some parts then do the following;

```
$limit = 512000; // set here a limit 
$sourceData = fread($s_handle,$limit); 

// your code ect..
```

Or with eof

```
$source='';
while (!feof($s_handle))
$source.=fread($s_handle,1024); // set limit
```

Comment: I'm still trying to make this work.  Does it require simplexml_load_file() or can I use it with fsockopen? (Its an issue, because some of the XML is not always well formed, but I can use it anyway as delimited data. Its not an RSS feed).  Jim H.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem.  I can get the partial data without trouble, but I still can't avoid loading the entire file first (and often timing out). That's the real problem. This is the code I'm using now.  Any ideas?  Works fine, except on very large files.



    $s_handle = fsockopen ($site, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if ($s_handle) {

    fwrite($s_handle, "GET " . $header . " HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " . $site. "\r\n\r\n");

 $limit = 512000; // set here a limit 
 $SourceData = fread($s_handle,$limit); 

        fclose ($s_handle);
    }